# Can you get an 2 dimensional array from 3 dimensional array without loops in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

Can you get a subarray from 3 dimensional array in Java? I'm kind of new to Java and need some help.

```
threeDimensions[][][] = {
    {
        {false, true, false, false},
        {false, true, false, false},
        {false, true, false, false},
        {false, true, false, false},
    },
    {
        {false, false, false, false},
        {false, true, true, false},
        {false, true, false, false},
        {false, true, false, false},
    }
};

twoDimensions = threeDimensions[0];
```

This way doesn't work but is there a way to do it without looping?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What is `threeDimensions`? Where is your type declaration? Arrays should be declared `boolean[] array` and not `boolean array[]` - the latter is legacy syntax and to be avoided.

Comment: "This way doesn't work" Could you be more specific about the "does not work" part? Please let us know what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: I know about declaration, but is gives me when I print it out danull

Comment: I'm expecting to get:
`twoDimensions = {
        {false, true, false, false},
        {false, true, false, false},
        {false, true, false, false},
        {false, true, false, false},
    },`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way does work, but you've just got the syntax a bit wrong. It should be

```
boolean[][][] threeDimensions = {
    {
        {false, true, false, false},
        {false, true, false, false},
        {false, true, false, false},
        {false, true, false, false},
    },
    {
        {false, false, false, false},
        {false, true, true, false},
        {false, true, false, false},
        {false, true, false, false},
    }
};

boolean[][] twoDimensions = threeDimensions[0];
```

If your problem is printing it out, you need to write

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(twoDimensions));
```

Answer (score 2):

It works as exactly as you think it works.
You just forgot to declare twoDimensions as a two-dimension array.
Do this:

```
Boolean twoDimensions[][] = threeDimensions[0];
```

Comment: I only need to use Boolean class?

Comment: Thanks, do you recommend using `Boolean` instead of `boolean`?

Comment: No, using Boolean or boolean does not matter in this case.
I was talking about the declaration of the variable twoDimensions.
Can you post the code where you declared twoDimensions?

The code pbabcdefp posted should work.